# how to enable a submit button after validations(empty text etc.) in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have created a form in ExtJS.

I am validating the text fields on the form e.g. if the fileds are empty or there are some ajax requests that are sent to the server and returs some results.

The Submit button is initially disabled, and what I want is to enable the button once the validations are done(if all validations are ok).

how can I achieve this???

Can anyone help in this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your TabPanel you could listen to one (or both) of the forms' 'clientvalidation' event and then enable/disable your submit button based on the outcome of each form's isValid method. Something like...

```
this.get(0).on('clientvalidation', function(){
    var button = this.getTopToolbar().get(0); //get a reference to your button

    button.setDisabled(!(this.get(0).isValid() && this.get(1).isValid()));
}, this);
```

Hope this helps
Stuart